# how can i filter array of objects by its property value? in Javascript/ React-native

Tags: javascript, react-native, object, filter

Plz help me masters. If I have data composed of objects, how can I filter them through their property value.

```
{id: 1, title: Tom, FinalTest: true}, 
{id:2, title: Maggie, FinalTest: false},
{id:3, title: Jake, FinalTest: true}
```

I want to filter object which propety FinalTest is true.

result

```
{id: 1, title: Tom, FinalTest: true}, 
{id:3, title: Jake, FinalTest: true}
```

Answer (score 0):

**May be this will help you:**

```js
const test = [
  { id: 1, title: "Tom", FinalTest: true },
  { id: 2, title: "Maggie", FinalTest: false },
  { id: 3, title: "Jake", FinalTest: true },
];

const result = test.filter((t) => t.FinalTest === true);
console.log(result)
```